# Plotting time series with different colors

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot some time series data where each data point has a label.

So lets say my time series has 365 points. I want to plot these 365 point with their respective colors. They are not spatial points. So I can just have a line where the segments of the line can have different color.

Answer (score 7):

check out [3D colored line plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23566-3d-colored-line-plot) and\or  [Colored line or scatter plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19476-colored-line-or-scatter-plot) both from the file exchange.

or if you want to do it yourself you can use `surface` :

```
x=linspace(-10,10,256);
y=sin(x);
c=1:numel(x);
colormap(jet(256)); % or whatever colormap you want
surface('XData',  [x(:) x(:)],'YData',[y(:) y(:)],...
        'ZData',0*[x(:) x(:)],'CData',[c(:) c(:)],'EdgeColor','flat');
```

[image]

You can read more on `surface` properties [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface_props.html).

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic, but couldn't think of [this image](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v450/Weareninja/hawhaw/mouth-rainbow.jpg) hahaha. Nice plot +1!