# use marker fill colors according to data value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using matlab to plot three data series. 
e.g.

```
0.4545 0.7676 10
0.3232 0.5432 20
```

Lets say this is a 100 x 3 matrix. (Lets call it A, also it is sorted according to A(:,1) )The third column is an additional number which ranges from 1 to 100. 
I am using MATLAB to do the following:

```
plot (A(:,1));
hold on;
plot (A(:,2));
```

I am using the property editor to represent data-series A(:,1) in line format and A(:,2) with additional marker [square i.e --rs option in plot].

My question is, how do I fill the squares according to data in the 3rd column ?

Basically how do i go about color coding the 2nd data-series according to data in 3d column ? 
In the figure attached, how do i fill color into the squares by data in A(:,3)
Would it be possible to make a gradation in the color by making a gradient ?

Please help. Thanks.

[image: Dataseries A(:,1) as red line, A(:,2) as blue squares]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very simple, not so efficient but very easy to read, way to do this:

```
% create fake data
x=linspace(-10,10,100);
y=sin(x);
c=randi(numel(x),1,numel(x));
cmap=colormap(jet(numel(x)));

% plot the lines
plot(x,y,'--'); hold on

% plot the squares, one at a time according to color vector c
% I added some randome noise to y to get the image nicer... 
for n=1:numel(x)
    plot(x(n),y(n)+0.3*(rand-0.5),'s','MarkerFaceColor',cmap(c(n),:));hold on
end
hold off
```

[image]

On a completely different not,  this question reminded me of an answer I gave a while ago on a similar subject ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754270/plotting-time-series-with-different-colors-in-matlab/18754961#18754961))...

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) function. It can take up to two extra parameters, the size of each point and the color.

To expand a bit:

You will need an `X` vector. Since you appear to be plotting against point number, you'll need to define one. For the color gradient, I typically go from blue to red, but you will need to play around with it to see what you like.

```
A = rand(100,3);
[M,N] = size(A);
X = 1:M;
S = 35; % size of symbols in pixels

% normalize vector to go from zero to 1
normValue = (A(:,3)-min(A(:,3)))./(max(A(:,3))-min(A(:,3)))

% this will do blue to red. play around with it to get the color scheme you want
C = [normValue zeros(size(normValue)) 1-normValue];

figure
scatter(X,A(:,1),S,C,'Marker','s')
line(X,A(:,2),'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
```

(This is a minimum working example, obviously replace the random data with your own) Note that `scatter` won't draw lines between the points, so you will have to either do without them or plot the data twice, first with a `plot` function and then with a `scatter` on top.

Comment: thanks. pretty neat. 
just one more additional question. how do i 'fill' color into the squares using the above generated color gradient. Above gives, outline of square colored according to the gradient.

Comment: how do i use 'markerfacecolor' with this ? this will do the filling part. im not sure how do i integrate with the code above.

Comment: You don't need 'MarkerFaceColor'. To fill in the face, add the flag `'fill'`. So the line would be `scatter(X,A(:,1),S,C,'fill','Marker','s')`