# Matlab - Colour markers in plot according to criteria

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

I have a quick question on a matlab plot. I want to draw a line with round markers on each point, but I want the markers to have a different color according to some criteria. I managed to display on the markers the different criteria but I was not able to change their colours.

To be more specific on the code below:

- d3 is a (1x240) vector of y values for the plot.
- RiskierInd is a (1x240) matrix with the criteria (it has values from
  1 to 12).

What I want is the markers with criteria 1 to be in one colour, markers with criteria 2 to be with another colour, and so on and so forth.

The code below plots the line with the markers and with the criteria inside the markers.

```
% plot the data
figure
d3 = vals;
n = 1:numel(d3);
plot(n,d3, '-ob','markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','w');
for idx = 1:numel(d3)
    text(n(idx),d3(idx), num2str(RiskierInd(idx)),...
         'FontSize',8,...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
end
```

[image]

I did check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120203/use-marker-fill-colors-according-to-data-value-in-matlab) post which is similar, but couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Also, is it possible to add a legend with the color of the markers afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatter` instead of `plot` for this. You can replace

```
plot(n,d3, '-ob','markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','w');
```

with

```
hold on
plot(n, d3,'b-');
scatter(n, d3, [], RiskierInd, 'filled');
caxis([1 12]);
```

Then, to display the correspondence between the colors and the values you can simply add `colorbar` to your code.

**Edit** If you want to define custom colors, you can use `colormap` with a custom n-by-3 array of RGB colors. For instance, to have exactly 12 colors you can do:

```
 colormap(jet(12));
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but got the following error:
Error using scatter (line 55)
Incorrect number of inputs for property-value pairs.

Comment: thanks! Works perfectly! Mind if I ask you 2 quick questions:
1) How exactly can I edit the color of each marker using colormap?
2) Is it possible to create a legend with the different colors? Using the legend command does not work ...

Comment: You can't have the legend working here, but the `colorbar` is as informative. You can look at the doc of `colormap` to define the colors that suits you ;-)

Comment: Ratbert, thanks for your comment. The only issue is that the colorbar shows a continuum of colors and I need exactly 12 colors.

Comment: Ratbert, perfect. Thank you very much. Just two final things:
Anyway I can replace the number entries on colourbar by strings? 
Also, can I choose each category colour?

Comment: Edit: Tried this: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/lcolorbar.html but got an error: "Unrecognized input or invalid parameter/value pair arguments."